# How to associate attributes from different classes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm facing a difficult to associate things on Rails. In this case, I have a model for locals, and a model to identifier a user token ( that came from another APi). A place has a rating ( a score from 0 to 5 ) associated with it, and every user has many ratings but just one for each place. Trying to do this I create a new model that has ratings attribute and I want to associate a rating id to just one place id.

```
# Description of User Identifier Class
class UserIdentifier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_locals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_rate, dependent: :destroy
  validates :identifier, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :identifier
  validates_uniqueness_of :identifier

  def self.find_favorites(params)
    UserIdentifier.find(params).favorite_locals
  end
end

# Model of Users Rates 
class UserRate < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user_identifier
    validates :rating, numericality: true
    validates_numericality_of :rating, less_than_or_equal_to: 5
    validates_numericality_of :rating, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
    validates :user_identifier, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo in the `has_many :user_rate, dependent: :destroy`. The association should be named `user_rates`, so the correct code for `UserIdentifier` model is:

```
class UserIdentifier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_locals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_rates, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end
```

Second, it's not clear how the "place" entity is named in your project. If it's `FavoriteLocal` then this is the code you need:

```
class UserRate < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user_identifier
    belongs_to :favorite_local
    # ...
end
```

If this is another model just define the belongs to association right below `belongs_to :user_identifier`. I hope you got the idea.